# How to properly add operators based on array result retreived from another operator in Apache Airflow?

Tags: airflow, airflow-2.x

I need to first read from BigQuery to get a list of SQL strings stored in a specific table then loop through the string array and run against BigQuery again to fix things. For running those SQLs I want to run them parallel to speed things up.

My problem is I know how to get back the result from the previous operator in PythonOperator but initializing BigQueryExecuteQueryOperator in function called by PythonOperator will not push task to Airflow.

Consider I am using Airflow 2, any ideas on how should I resolve such issue?

Comment: are you familiar with dynamic-task-mapping ?

Comment: Thanks @ozs, this does shred some light of what I can try. https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.3.0/concepts/dynamic-task-mapping.html#putting-it-all-together

Comment: @KabilanMohanraj I was using PythonOperator to execute `BigQueryGetDataOperator` to get the SQLs, but my current approah is to run `BigQueryGetDataOperator` directly and get those SQLs in SubDagOperator via xcom but not sure how to get it.

Comment: Great thank you to @ozs. Problem solved easily with Dynamic Task Mapping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR: Just avoid to use operators but TaskFlow API, everything is simpler. Tradition operators are pretty rigid and hard to deal with IMO.

If you search in Google for passing result from operator to another operator  or parent DAG to sub DAG, usually you will find a Jinja2 template to pull result from Xcom, yet many people found it is not working. The result is because not all fields will be interpolated but `those registered in Operator` `template_fields` will be rendered.

https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/concepts/operators.html#jinja-templating

> You can also use Jinja templating with nested fields, as long as these nested fields are marked as templated in the structure they belong to: fields registered in template_fields property will be submitted to template substitution

---

The solution is to run the operator and pass to TaskFlow decorated function with `@task` and expand result from operator by `.expand`. Feels a lot clear on what is actually running? Yeah, just use TaskFlow API mainly and traditional operators only if needed.

https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.3.0/concepts/dynamic-task-mapping.html#putting-it-all-together

```py
    get_all_ddl_fixing_sqls = BigQueryGetDataOperator(
        task_id='get_all_ddl_fixing_sqls',
        dataset_id='my_dataset',
        table_id='my_ddl_fixing_table',
        selected_fields='ddl',
        max_results=9999999, # Default is 100, maybe -1 equals to unlimited, I have not tried
        dag=dag
    )

    # Workers might time out occasionally, remember to retry
    @task(retries=5)
    def fix_bq_schema_by_prepared_ddl(ddl_fixing_sql):
        BigQueryHook(use_legacy_sql=False).insert_job(
            location='asia-east2',
            configuration={
                'query': {
                    'query': ddl_fixing_sql[0],
                    'projectId': project_id,
                    'datasetId': dataset_id,
                    'useLegacySql': False,
                },
            },
        )

    fix_bq_schema_by_prepared_ddl = fix_bq_schema_by_prepared_ddl.partial().expand(
        ddl_fixing_sql=XComArg(get_all_ddl_fixing_sqls)
    )
```